# How to code "for tuple in multiple range"?

Tags: kotlin

For example:

```
for ((x, y) in (1..100, 50 downTo 0)) {}
```

```
for ((x, y, z) in (1..100, 50 downTo 0, 500..1000 step 2)) {}
```

I have found the official kotlin document: [Destructuring Declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html), but still can't write correct code.

Comment: For your first example, do you want all combinations of tuples? ie `{(x,y) | x in [1, 100] and y in [0, 50]}`? (<- that's math notation, not python syntax)

Comment: @SyntaxVoid  Yes.

Comment: Maybe [`zip`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html) is what you are looking for, e.g.: `(1..100).zip(50 downTo 0).forEach { (x, y) -> /* do something */ }`...

Comment: For triple values it is a bit more complicated... `(1..100).zip(50 downTo 0).zip(500..1000 step 2).forEach { (xy, z) -> xy.also { (x, y) -> /* do something with x, y and z */ } }`... Note that if any of those ranges finishes earlier, it will stop with the latest possible value... e.g. in the last example the highest `z` would be `600`...

Comment: if you want to have all values combined with each other instead, you may just want to nest those loops instead, e.g. `for (x in 1..100) { for (y in 50 downTo 0) { for (z in 500..1000 step 2) { /* do something with x, y and z */ }}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `zipOf` function, which returns a `Sequence` of all possible combinations. Here are 3 overloads of this function:

```
fun <T1, T2> zipOf(first: Iterable<T1>, second: Iterable<T2>) = sequence {
    for (t1 in first)
        for (t2 in second)
            yield(t1 to t2)
}

fun <T1, T2, T3> zipOf(first: Iterable<T1>, second: Iterable<T2>, third: Iterable<T3>) = sequence {
    for (t1 in first)
        for (t2 in second)
            for (t3 in third)
                yield(Triple(t1, t2, t3))
}

fun <T> zipOf(vararg iterables: Iterable<T>): Sequence<List<T>> =
    iterables.fold(sequenceOf(emptyList())) { result, iterable ->
        result.flatMap { list -> iterable.asSequence().map { elm -> list + elm } }
    }
```

You can use them like this:

```
for ((x, y) in zipOf(1..100, 50 downTo 0)) {}
for ((x, y, z) in zipOf(1..100, 50 downTo 0, 500..1000 step 2)) {}
for ((x, y, z, w) in zipOf(1..100, 50 downTo 0, 500..1000 step 2, 0..1)) {}
```